# php directory read and delete existing files

Tags: php

I am trying to make sure that when the user uploads a profile picture, there can only be one image within the dir "profile_pic". I am openning and reading the dir with a while loop but the @unlink is not working. Below is the php code:

```
        $directory = "uploads\\".$id."\images\profile_pic\\";
        if (glob($directory . "*.jpg") != false) {
            $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.jpg"));
            if ($filecount > 0) {
                //delete exiting pics in folder profile_pic
                $handle = opendir($directory);
                while ($handle && ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
                    if ( unlink($entry)) {
                    $msg .= "File Deleted";
                    }
                }
                closedir($directory);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just force the image to be renamed to "featured.jpg", and replace existing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, where did you define `$entry` - did you ever assign a value to it? And why do you make exactly the same call to `glob()` twice instead of catching the result of the first call in a variable? And why bother to `opendir()` to list files when you have already `glob()`ed and obtained that list of files? Especially when you don't apply the same `*.jpg` filter to the files you are deleting...

Just do this:

```
// Forward slashes work on Windows too (in PHP, at least)
$directory = "uploads/".$id."/images/profile_pic";

if (($existing = glob($directory . "/*.jpg")) !== false) { // Get a list of files...
  foreach ($existing as $file) { // ...loop them...
    $msg .= (unlink($directory."/".$file)) ? "File $file deleted\n" : "Could not delete $file\n"; // ...and delete them
  }
} else $msg .= "Listing directory failed\n";
```